# why does python date time fail for {Date}2016-11-22T11:49:21.826-05:00 even though format matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am trying to format date time in python 3.6 as follows,

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "{Date}%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
```

However the formatting fails for input string `{Date}2016-11-22T11:49:21.826-05:00` with below error.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./test-date.py", line 168, in get_date
>   date_time_ = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "{Date}%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z").replace(tzinfo=None)   
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
>   tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)   
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
>   (data_string, format))
> ValueError: time data '{Date}2016-11-22T11:49:21.826-05:00' does not match format '{Date}%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
> ```

Comment: The ability to parse a time zone offset with a colon in it via `strptime()`'s `%z` format was added in Python 3.7.  In 3.6, it's expecting something like `-0500` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the correct way to feed `%z` is something like `-0500` not `-05:00`.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-11-22T11:49:21.826-0500', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 22, 11, 49, 21, 826000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 68400)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind using an additional Python package named `dateutil`, you can do the following:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
ds = '2016-11-22T11:49:21.826-05:00'
print(parse(ds))
```

Output:

```
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 22, 11, 49, 21, 826000, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))
```